# Mostrar un registro mediante un JOptionPane y boton en java

Tags: java, java-swing

El programa es una interfaz de una alcancia
Tengo problemas para hacer un boton en java que pregunte cuantas monedas se desean agregar de un mismo valor y que la cantidad se agregue al total , tambien al cerrar la ventana de la aplicacion deberia mostrar el registro de operacion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Trate de hacer un metodo de validacion para cerrar la ventana pero no me funciono

```
btnUnPesos.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            depositar(Alcancia.Denominaciones.UNO);
        }
    });
      btnCincoCentavos.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            depositar(Alcancia.Denominaciones.CINCOCENTAVOS);
        }
    });
```

Asi es como hice los botones para la moneda de 1 peso y 5 centavos

```
private void depositar(Alcancia.Denominaciones d) {
    try {
        alc.echarMoneda(d);
        txtTotal.setText(alc.getTotalAhorrado()+"");
        txtAgregados.setText(alc.getCantidadDeMonedas()+"");
    } catch (EstaRotaExcepcion e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ya está rota",
                ":( Error :(",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Porfavor un poco de ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Para ingresar una cantidad de monedas puedes utilizar un JOptionPane al presionar el botón quedaría así

```
btnUnPesos.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String cantidad = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("¿Cual es la cantidad?");
        System.out.println(cantidad);
        depositar(Alcancia.Denominaciones.UNO,cantidad);
    }
});
private void depositar(Alcancia.Denominaciones d,int cantidad) {
int total = d * cantidad;
    try {
    alc.echarMoneda(total);
    txtTotal.setText(alc.getTotalAhorrado()+"");
    txtAgregados.setText(alc.getCantidadDeMonedas()+"");
    } catch (EstaRotaExcepcion e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ya está rota",
            ":( Error :(",
            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

para el mensaje al cerrar la ventana agrega en evento al frame

```
        this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public  void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Reporte que deseas mostrar","Mensaje",JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION);
        }
    });
```

Si deseas personalizar el JOptionPane puedes verlo aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267562/making-a-jpanel-into-a-joptionpane-ok-option